# GNOME settings without GUI

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, raspberry-pi, debian, gnome

I am trying to run a VNC server on a Raspberry Pi which I don't have physical access to.
I've installed `realvnc-vnc-server` and enabled VNC in `raspi-config`

I'm running into an issue with encryption on the VNC service - trying to connect from OSX using the built in Screen Sharing application.
I've seen this issue before on Ubuntu, and normally follow the steps in this answer to resolve it; http://askubuntu.com/questions/463486/can-no-longer-use-screen-share-to-connect-mac-to-ubuntu-since-upgrading-to-14-04

However as I have no GUI to open `dconf-editor` I'm not sure where to change the `require-encryption` setting. I have read about `gsettings` but I can't figure out which package(s) to install to use it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Thanks, I never know which community is best suited, so have posted it there now. Cheers!